# What insect eggs are these?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, eggs

There are only 3 eggs. A pink colour with stripes on it. Is it possible to identify the species? Found right below a window, on the wood.
I'm in Bangalore,
India. [image]

Answer (score 8):

These are caterpillar/butterfly eggs belonging to the *Rounded Palm-Redeye* (Erionota torus).

Here is an example of the eggs of a leaf:
[image]

The larvae / caterpillar form looks like this:
[image]

And fully formed butterfly looks like this:
[image]

All these pictures can be found on the iNaturalist page for this taxon:
https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/219475-Erionota-torus/browse_photos?quality_grade=any&photo_license=any&place_id=32239

And the geographical range of observations of this species includes your area:
[image]

Comment: Nice answer! +1. (Never thought I'd think, "Ugly butterfly...")

Comment: @anongoodnurse it used up all the pretty on its eggs.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes, I my first impression of the adult was that it was a moth

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the answer! I've seen these around the house!